# Start VM, run exe, stop VM in azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I want to start an exe that is located in a VM every day. The exe is 5 minutes long, so I want to use azure automation to start the vm, run the exe, and when it's finished, stop the vm.

I've looked at some resources on the web, and I can start the VM with :

```
Start-AzureVM -Name $VMName -ServiceName $ServiceName
```

I've seen in examples that people stop vm in other job at a certain time, but is it possible to start the vm, run an exe and stop the vm when the exe has terminated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start the VM via automation, and then fire off the exe from a Powershell script. When the exe exits you could call Stop-AzureVM / Stop-AzureRmVM

Comment: I can stop the VM inside the VM ?

Comment: Azure doesn't care where you send it a command from. As long as it is authenticated it will process it and once it has accepted a command it doesn't need to be able to report back.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell Remoting

Yes, you can use a PowerShell Remoting session, which sits on top of Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to achieve this.

The high-level workflow for your Azure Automation Runbook would look something like:

```
Start-AzureVM ...
Invoke-Command ...
Stop-AzureVM ...
```

The `Invoke-Command` PowerShell command creates a PowerShell Remoting session (PSSession) to the Azure Virtual Machine, using the VM's public WinRM endpoint. The command will run synchronously by default, unless you use the `-AsJob` parameter to execute the command as a PowerShell Background Job, on the Runbook Worker. If you choose to invoke the remote command (your exe file) as a Background Job, then you can use the `Wait-Job` command to wait for its completion, before calling `Stop-AzureVM`.

## IaaSv1 or IaaSv2?

Another major factor in your automation work, is considering whether you are using Azure Service Management (ASM) or Azure Resource Manager (ARM). Azure has two different APIs, and depending on how you created your VM, you will be using one or the other.

ASM = IaaSv1 (classic VMs)
ARM = IaaSv2

When you provision IaaS VMs in ASM, they **must** be a member of a "Cloud Service" container. Conversely, in ARM / IaaSv2, you can create VM instances as top-level members of your Azure subscription (account), with the caveat that **all** ARM-based cloud resources **must** be deployed into a "Resource Group."

ASM and ARM have *entirely separate* PowerShell modules. The ASM command is `Start-AzureVM` and the ARM equivalent is `Start-AzureRmVM`. Due to the inherent differences in the ASM and ARM architecture, these two commands also have different parameters. The ASM version requires that you specify the "Cloud Service" that the IaaS VM belongs to, whereas the ARM version requires that you specify the "Resource Group" that the VM belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever may visit here, here is the example of Start VM, Run a script and stop VM.

https://github.com/shanjin14/AzureAutomation

In the RunPython.ps1 just need to put the full file path to the exe file
such as "C:\abc.exe"

Cheers. hope it helps